# WPF/MVVM Load an UserControl at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i know that there a many articles about my problem but i cant find a solution.
I am new in WPF - MVVM and i try to understand the MVVM-Logic.
So i made a little project to understand that.
For my later apps i want to load UserControls dynamicly to my Window.

In my StartView i have a Binding to the StartViewModel.
(The Binding is in the APP.xaml)

```
StartView app = new StartView();
StartViewModel context = new StartViewModel();
```

The StartView

```
<Window x:Class="test.Views.StartView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="516">
    <Grid>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,404,239">
            <MenuItem Header="_Einstellungen">
                <MenuItem Header="Server" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding LoadedControl}" Margin="0,28,0,128" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the StartViewModel

```
namespace test.ViewModel
{
    public class StartViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields
        private UCStastistikViewModel _loadedControl;
        #endregion

        public StartViewModel()
        {
            LoadedControl = new UCStastistikViewModel();
        }

        #region Properties / Commands
        public UCStastistikViewModel LoadedControl
        {
            get { return _loadedControl; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _loadedControl)
                    return;

                _loadedControl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoadedControl");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #endregion
    }
}
```

UCStatistikView

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.Views.UCStatistik"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="188" d:DesignWidth="508">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:UCStastistikViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="red">       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UCStatistikViewModel

```
namespace test.ViewModel
{
    public class UCStastistikViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields
        #endregion

        public UCStastistikViewModel()
        {
        }

        #region Properties / Commands
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now i want to load my UCStatistikView in the ContentControl of my StartView.
But in the Startview only the Path test.UCStatistikViewModel is shown instead of the whole UC
Can anybody give me some Ideas where my problem is / where im am going wrong ?

Bye j

Comment: How you try to do the assignment?

Comment: How do you assign a usercontrol to `contentcontrol` and get a wrong resut?

Comment: I use Databinding. In my ViewModel is a Property LoadedControl. In the construcor of the StartViewModel i put an instance of the UC in this Property.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your ViewModels should not care about UserControls. Instead, have them hold ViewModels, and let WPF resolve how to draw the ViewModel with a DataTemplate.

For example,

```
<Window x:Class="test.Views.StartView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test.Views"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="516">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:UCStastistikViewModel}">
            <views:UCStastistikView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,404,239">
            <MenuItem Header="_Einstellungen">
                <MenuItem Header="Server" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding LoadedControl}" Margin="0,28,0,128" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also, get rid of the `<UserControl.DataContext>` in your UserControl. The `DataContext` should be passed in by whatever is using the control, not defined in the UserControl :)

**Edit**

Based on your comment to an earlier answer about switching out the content of the StartPage by switching a ViewModel, you may be interested in looking at [this post of mine](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/). It's titled `Navigation with MVVM`, however the same concept applies for switching Views or UserControls

Basically, you'd make the property `LoadedControl` of type `ViewModelBase` instead of hard-coding it's type, and then set it to whatever object you want displayed in your ContentControl. WPF's DataTemplates will take care of hooking up the correct View for the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you very much. I have already read parts of your Blog and its very helpful.

Comment: @user1121575 Hrrrmm I thought parts of the code in your question looked familiar :)

Answer (score 2):

WPF doesn't support automatic resolution of the view for a given view model. The naive solution to your problem would be to directly add the UCStatistikView to your StartView and bind the VM to it

```
<Window x:Class="test.Views.StartView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="516">
<Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,404,239">
        <MenuItem Header="_Einstellungen">
            <MenuItem Header="Server" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <UCStatistikView DataContext="{Binding LoadedControl}" Margin="0,28,0,128" />
</Grid>
```

A more elaborated approach would be to implement a ViewLocator (view model first approach) or a ViewModelLocator (view first approach). The locator automatically locates and binds the view(s) to a view model. There are some MVVM frameworks/toolkits out there which implement such a locator.

- [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/): Offers a flexible ViewLocator and ViewModelLocator based on naming conventions. [Here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/12/16/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-7-all-about-conventions.aspx) is an article about them
- [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/): Offers a ViewModelLocator. [Here](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/04/wpfs-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-i/) is an introduction

With Caliburn.Micro you start view would look like this

```
<Window x:Class="test.Views.StartView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="516">
<Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,404,239">
        <MenuItem Header="_Einstellungen">
            <MenuItem Header="Server" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl cm:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}" Margin="0,28,0,128" />
</Grid>
```

The `cm:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}"` attached property tells caliburn to locate the view for the view model which is bound and set the `Content` property of the ContentControl to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should do:

The StartView:

```
<Window x:Class="test.Views.StartView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="516">
    <Grid>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,404,239">
            <MenuItem Header="_Einstellungen">
                <MenuItem Header="Server" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <UCStatistikView x:Name="myUCStatistikView" Margin="0,28,0,128" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the StartViewModel:

```
namespace test.ViewModel
{
    public class StartViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private UCStastistikViewModel _myControlViewModel;

        public StartViewModel()
        {
            _myControlViewModel = new UCStastistikViewModel();
        }

        public UCStastistikViewModel MyControlViewModel
        {
            get { return _myControlViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _myControlViewModel)
                    return;

                _myControlViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyControlViewModel");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UCStatistikView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.Views.UCStatistik"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="188" d:DesignWidth="508">
    <Grid Background="red">       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind of your StartView:

```
this.myUCStatistikView.DataContext = ((StartViewModel)this.DataContext).MyControlViewModel;
```

After having tested different approaches, my conclusion is that the best way for datacontext bindings is the code-behind of the parent view in case you have userControls.

*EDIT*: ViewModel locators are fine for trivial examples but if your ViewModel must be instantiated dynamically (it's mostly the case when its constructor requires parameters), the you can't use it.
I personally stopped using locators because of this.

Comment: ok, but later i want to have a navigation on the top with btn1,btn2 and btn3. if btn1 is pressed UserControl1 should be loaded in the ContentControl or another placeholder. If btn2 is pressed UserControl2 should be loaded and all other controls unloaded or hided. So the logic of loading and unloading UCs should be in the ViewModel, or not ?

Comment: This wasn't really obvious in the question ;)
Ok, the simplest way is to add `UserControl1`, `UserControl2`, `UserControl3` statically in the XAML of your view, and then hide them using a binding on the `Visibility` property, depending on the button that is pressed.
You can instantiate and expose as public properties all 3 viewmodels of your usercontrols in the `StartViewModel`.
I also recommend using a converter to bind a bool property of your viewmodel to the `Visibility` property of your controls. See http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/.

Comment: @ken2k you can use a ViewModelLocator in conjunction with a DI container to inject the dependencies into a viewmodel. Thats what caliburn does anyway

Answer (score -1):

Review :- http://patelrocky1608.wordpress.com/2013/12/26/how-to-add-custom-control-dynamically-in-wpf/

Which Contain Whole Code For Understand UserControl Dynamically..

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of that post as part of your answer. In its current state, this answer is incomplete.

Comment: First You See There Is Full Code For Create User Control Dynamically And It Is Usefull For New Learner.. And Next Time I try To Wite Code At Comment..